# A joined query in CakePHP 3 is failing to detect the first column's ID. How can I solve this?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I recently uploaded a project to a testing server from XAMPP and started running into some differences in the environment immediately. 
The first thing I'm up against is this:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.id' in 'where clause'

```
    $query = $this->find()->where(['users.id' => $Id])->hydrate(false)->join([
        'table' => 'userdata',
        'alias' => 'u',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => 'u.userID = users.id'
         ])->autoFields(true) // selecting all fields from current table
        ->select(["u.avatar", "u.birthday", "u.views", "u.bio", "u.lastIP"]);       

    return $query->toArray();
```

This worked fine in Xampp, but on a Linux server is producing the above error.

`$this->find()`

is located in the model for Users, so it focuses on that table initially.

It's directly caused by the join - without it, the users.id works perfectly. I believe a solution would be to give users.id an alias, but that may not be correct.

How could this be solved?

Comment: According to the CakePHP conventions, the alias should be camel capsed, ie `Users`, not `users`. That being said, when you encounter SQL errors, please always show the generated SQL query - thanks!

Comment: Could you make this an answer, please? This was indeed the solution and I'd like to accept it.

Comment: Considering lower-case letters worked on Xampp, I believe that the notation settings were different.

Answer (score 0):

I don't do CakePHP, but I do sql. I don't see where you included the "users" table with that field in it. I only see inclusion and aliasing of userdata (aliased to "u"). but there's no "users" table, unless this is elsewhere in your code (which would probably have been good to include, even for those who do know cake, as this is explicitly what the error is stating).

Unless Cake is expected to make an assumption about the users table, it would appear that it's not included until I see evidence otherwise ;)

Thanks for the Cake intro.

Also, you may want to turn on mysql logging to verify that the cake framework is creating the join correctly (ie: view the Full Query all at once in the mysql log)

Comment: I added a little aside for those unfamiliar. CakePHP 3 is essentially a light MVC framework that also wraps some decent security and database structures as well - but otherwise lets you create what you need on top of it. It's got some useful helpers as well.

Comment: For the table in question, the query is located in the model of the table - it grabs it automatically in the $this->()

Comment: As mentioned: Until I see the code that demonstrates "this", I don't know for sure that the field is present. Also, you may want to turn on mysql logging to verify that the cake framework is creating the join correctly (ie: view the Full Query all at once in the mysql log). With that full query, I'll be able to tell you what went wrong ... but translating it into Cake is all on you ;)